Установка библиотеки winshell python на windows 10
Пример с официального сайта winshell
https://winshell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/shortcuts.html#create-a-shortcut-to-a-file
import os, sys
import winshell

shortcut = winshell.shortcut(sys.executable)
shortcut.working_directory = "c:/temp"
shortcut.write(os.path.join(winshell.desktop(), "python.lnk"))
shortcut.dump()

При установке библиотеки (https://winshell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)
pip install winshell

Выдает следующее сообщение
PS C:\Users\bro> pip install winshell
Requirement already satisfied: winshell in c:\python\python312\lib\site-packages (0.6)

При запуске скрипта, пишет ошибку
"C:\Python\proekt\09 - Создание прфиля chrome\pythonProject\.venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Python\proekt\09 - Создание прфиля chrome\pythonProject\main.py" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\proekt\09 - Создание профиля chrome\pythonProject\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import winshell
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winshell'

Как тогда установить библиотеку winshell  и использовать?

Модуль безошибочно устанавливается и импортируется. Проверьте используемые интерпретатор и окружение в котором запускаете скрипт (Вы могли установить библиотеку для одного интерпретатора, а скрипт запустить в другом).

Наверное запустить скрипт с помощью интерпретатора, а не в интерпретаторе?

исправлено:  Для одного окружения, а скрипт запустить в другом.

Что-то подобное и произошло, но это очень интересный баг. Надо разбираться. Интерпретатор используемый в среде программирования pyaharm, внезапно отличается от установленного в системе для текущего проекта, как это получилось - ума не приложу. По умолчанию путь к интерпретатору стоит как к установленному python.

Если у кого-то возникла подобная ошибка, я нашел проблему.
Конечно, нужно оговаривать, когда задаешь вопрос, в какой среде вы запускаете python скрипт. А запускал я его в pycharm
Так вот, при создании проекта, pysherm пишет, что используется интерпретатор установленный в системе, а когда смотришь параметры проекта, то выясняется, что интерпретатор установлен локальный, то есть только для данного проекта без всех установленных в системе библиотек и их для конкретного проекта надо прописывать заново

Выбирать надо интерпретатор системный, либо устанавливать библиотеки для проекта.
Ошибка была в том, что я хотел использовать системный интерпретатор, при написании скрипта, чтобы запускать его без среды программирования

